# Squid 2.7 and the client header max-age=0

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid

I'm trying to use squid as a reverse cache proxy in front of a php application in the same machine and never let the user to reach the backend, always load stale cache in background.

---

I'm using a self compiled squid 2.7-Stable9 with Centos 6.3 (x86_64) in the port 80 and the apache+php is in the same machine with the port 8000.

The apache+php response header sends this to squid:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=10, stale-while-revalidate=15, stale-if-error=20');
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

When I ask for a page to squid, first time revalidates and next time uses always stale, but this works with the **DISABLE CACHE** cache option of Firefox WebDevelopersTools extension.

The difference is that when cache is not disabled, client sends **Cache-control: max-age=0** and **If-Modified-Since** and squid connects to the backend always and revalidates.

In Squid 3.2 it worked as expected using **ignore-cc** but in 2.7 there is not such option.

Here is my squid.conf:

```
# http_port public_ip:port accel defaultsite= default hostname, if not provided
http_port 80 accel defaultsite=mydomain.com

# IP and port of your main application server (or multiple)
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8000 0 no-query originserver name=main
cache_peer_domain main mydomain.com

# Do not tell the world that which squid version we're running
httpd_suppress_version_string on

# Remove the Caching Control header for upstream servers
header_access Cache-Control deny all

# log all incoming traffic in Apache format
logformat combined %>a %ui %un [%tl] "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %Hs %<st "%{Referer}>h" "%{User-Agent}>h" %Ss:%Sh
access_log /usr/local/squid/var/logs/squid.log combined all

cache_effective_user squid

refresh_pattern nocache=true 0 0% 0

icp_port 0
```

I want to select the cache time in the php application and never let the user to see the latency of revalidating, that's why I'm using version 2.7 with stale-while-revalidate.

---

Example of request with cache enabled:

```
GET /some-page HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1 FirePHP/0.7.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
x-insight: activate
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 10:14:52 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 10:29:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (PowerStack)
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 10:29:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from localhost:80
Via: 1.1 localhost:80 (squid)
Connection: close
```

Example with cache disabled (what I want to happen):

```
GET /some-page HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1 FirePHP/0.7.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
x-insight: activate

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 10:36:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (PowerStack)
Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 10:36:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Age: 2
Content-Length: 16725
X-Cache: HIT from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from localhost:80
Via: 1.1 localhost:80 (squid)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution described here: [How to use in squid 2.7 the 3.1 feature "ignore-cc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846107/how-to-use-in-squid-2-7-the-3-1-feature-ignore-cc)

---

Well, after trying all alternatives, I modified the source code to implement the feature.

I changed in the **Squid-2.7-stable9** the file **src/refresh.c**:*282*:

```
282:    if (request) {
```

for

```
282:    if (request && FALSE) {
```

---

They do something like that in the 3.X to implement ignoreCc:

```
269:    if (request && !request->flags.ignore_cc) {
```

Worked as expected.