# How to use in squid 2.7 the 3.1 feature "ignore-cc"

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid

There is any way to ignore client "**Cache-Control: max-age=0**" and always let squid to return **stale content**?

In Squid 3.2 works using "ignore-cc" and the request never reaches backend (only while revalidating), always is stale but in Squid 2.7 works fine unless you send the **Cache-control: max-age=0** and **If-Modified-Since** headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying all alternatives, I modified the source code to implement the feature.

I changed in the **Squid-2.7-stable9** the file **src/refresh.c**:*282*:

```
282:    if (request) {
```

for

```
282:    if (request && FALSE) {
```

---

They do something like that in the 3.X to implement ignoreCc:

```
269:    if (request && !request->flags.ignore_cc) {
```

Worked as expected.